# Is there any way to save all changes a user has made to an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, save

I have a program in the form of an HTML page that contains both draggable/droppable elements and contenteditable elements. Is there any way to save both the positions of the elements as well as the contenteditable text? There may be over a hundred of each type of element, and I can't premake their ids, because they are generated when a button is clicked. I've looked into using localStorage but haven't found anything that pertains to my problem. It has to be an easy solution that I can apply to everything as it happens.

Here is my shortened HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <style>
            td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
            .tile {
                cursor: move;
                min-width: 48px;
                width: fit-content;
                height: 24px;
                background-color: red;
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="addTileButton">Click to add tile</button>
        <div contenteditable="true" id="tableDiv">
            <table cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <colgroup width="509"></colgroup>
                <colgroup span="5" width="166"></colgroup>
                <tr>
                    <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">State Name</font></b></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">GA (P)</font></b></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">C.3</font></b></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">ExCom</font></b></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">HRC</font></b></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><b><font face="Cambria">SC</font></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom>Afghanistan</td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom>Albania</td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom>Algeria</td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="32" align="left" valign=bottom>Andorra</td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font></td>
                    <td align="left" valign=bottom bgcolor="#999999"><font face="Cambria"><br></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#addTileButton").click(function() {
        $("body").append("<div id=draggable></div>");
        var tile = $("<div class=tile contenteditable=true></div>");
        $("#draggable").append(tile);
        $(".tile").draggable().resizable();
        $("#tableDiv").droppable();
        $("<td>").resizable();
    });
});
```

Any and all advice is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to do this. 
1) Save the whole html in which user has made changes, as a template.
This is not advisable as `while saving` the page, it can be noticed that some of the `information is lost`.

2) Save the `whole html structure of the div which you need in a javascript variable` and store it in a database. When needed get it from the server and display it as it is by simply making the `innerHtml` of the parentDiv to the data you got from the server.

3) The method which i would personally prefer. `Save the state of your html div in a JSON format` ( `information like width, height, positions, images of divs`, etc. ). Store that in the database. Now make a `rest API` and get the `JSON` data whenever needed. Parse it and display it as you need it to be displayed. A much cleaner approach !!!

Comment: Please read my last comment on the first answer and answer it as it pertains to your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @GabrielSchetter you can get all those properties from the `DOM`. For eg. `document.getElementById('myDiv')` to get the element and then get its properties. You can get more info in the [link](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm)  . I would prefer, if possible use `jQuery`, things will become `much easier` if you use that. For eg. to get an element's position you simple need to do `$('#myDiv').position()`.

Comment: The elements generated with the button have a have the same class, and giving them each individual ids would be a terribly complicated process (I think). While it may work for something with under a couple hundred elements, I don't think it's what I'm looking for. Please tell me if I've missed something.

Comment: @GabrielSchetter you dont need to give seperate ids to seperate elements for accessing them. I was just giving an example to make it more clear. Anyways, you can traverse through your table( in a loop, `.each()` function in jQuery ) and save the position of its child. Got my point ? I hope its helpful.

Comment: I vaguely understand what you mean. Could you give me an example code? Thank you for sticking with me. :)

Comment: ya sure buddy ! we are here to build a helping community :) Here you go. Check this [codepen link](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/EgRVok). And see how i have accessed the position of `child spans` without giving them seperate ids.

Comment: Ah... if only everyone here had that attitude... I'll check the link, thanks. :)

Comment: So you're suggesting that I get the position of each element created with the button with some sort of loop, (presumably using .each) and then recreate those element positions?

Comment: @GabrielSchetter Ya exactly.  Nd y only position,  you can get any attribute you want,  like image,  width,  height,  etc.  Hope this makes sense now :)

Answer (score -1):

The best way for it to do it is to save the state of each object on a json and save that on a database. So with the help of a rest api you can fetch the data back and rebuild everything from the same state json that you created.

**Edited -** 
So what i've done in a similar project is to take all the html properties data like width, height, position x and y etc and store it on an object like

```
    "input1": {
      "text": "Hello",
      "placeholder": "Put a text in here!",
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "100%",
      "position" : {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 10
      }
    }
```

Put all your objects in one and pass that as a JSON on the server and then rebuild it from the same object. 
*You will need more than just javascript for that for sure.*

Comment: Could you explain this process? I'm not very familiar with JSON.

Comment: JSON is like XML. It's just a format to save data, based on familiar JS syntax.

Comment: In order to use your updated suggestion, am I having to input all of these things, or is there some way I can automatically get them just based on element positioning? Again, I can't enter everything in, because I don't know any of the information beforehand.

Comment: I would suggest first to create a placement (div) with an id maybe to have all the other objects in it.
Then create a function to read an HTML object properties and build an object with the info you want.
Lastly on save for each HTML object you can call this function and save the return in a global state.
This global state variable/object you can parse it as JSON or whatever.